# jQuery Mobile - IE casching problem

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, cross-browser

Im using jQuery mobile to make a small project. You can say its a signup system for a weekly event, and then the event is reset each week (through some scripts running on a server).

I have had problems with IE before, since it has the most wack cashing properties ever, and therefore won't update page content when ajax requests are using GET. I then turned all my ajax into POST and it worked. Now, how do i do this in jQuery Mobile?

Everythings works great in firefox, but IE just won't update my content since the page are loaded through the ajax GET command. I tried to pass this into my custom js file to get it away, but it still dosen't work :(

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.extend(  $.mobile , {
                ajaxLinksEnabled : false
        });
    });
});
```

Anyone with an idea on what to do :)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

called on page initialization (befor doing the real request).

Comment: I actually don't have anything in my custom js file (yet). would i just set this in the start of $(document).ready() ?

Comment: Worked kinda. Still had some minor problems, but i added a bocus get var to force IE to load the page every time. Thanks again, and i hope all in the IE department at MS steps in dog poo!